# GROUP BY сортировать время

Tags: mysql, sql

как с помощью GROUP BY  сортировать время с 15 мин разницой то-есть есть столбцы

```
    time 
    2019-03-11 00:00:00
    2019-03-11 00:00:00
    2019-03-11 00:15:00
    2019-03-11 00:15:00
    2019-03-11 00:30:00
    2019-03-11 00:30:00
    2019-03-11 00:45:00
    2019-03-11 00:45:00

надо получить 
2019-03-11 00:15:00 value : 2
2019-03-11 00:30:00 value : 2
2019-03-11 00:45:00 value : 2
```

раньше был запрос `SELECT SUM(1) as value, data FROM stat  GROUP BY data 
Буду благодарен за любые предложения`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345308/5741205

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION `DATETIMEQUARTERS`(`INPUT_DATE_TIME` DATETIME) 
RETURNS DATETIME 
COMMENT 'Функция округляет время до предыдущего 15 минутного интервала' 
RETURN SEC_TO_TIME ((TIME_TO_SEC(INPUT_DATE_TIME) DIV 900 ) * 900)

//Использовать функцию
GROUP BY DATETIMEQUARTERS(datecolumn)
```

Comment: `group by floor(minute(date)/15)` несколько проще. правда конечно он не может вернуть красивое время